# Refresh page after being redirected

Tags: php, forms, refresh

I'm using a form in one of my pages that takes action in another one using PHP.

When the action is over, it redirects the user to the previous page. What I wonder is if there is any way to refresh the page, where the form is, after being redirected from the action page.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this JavaScript code at the end of the page:

```
<script language="javascript">
  window.location.replace("abc.php");
  window.reload();
 
 </script>
```

Comment: Just adding location.reload on the bottom of the page will always reload the page not in the particular event. He/She can simply use php header function (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) in action page to reload the prev page.

Comment: It reloads the page continuosly.. is there any way to stop it?

Comment: i'm using header('Location: ' . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] ); in action page but it doesn't reload de previous page neither.